# RESTful URL style guide for searching

Tags: rest, url, parameters, naming-conventions, query-string

If one is allowed to put multiple values on single Query Parameter,

should the parameter name be in singular or plural form?

```
/user?status=1,2,3
```

vs

```
/user?statuses=1,2,3
```

I tried to google it but no one covers about this specific matter

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your endpoint allows a user to query for a number of statuses, then you would use the plural of status i.e.

```
/user?statuses=1,2,3
```

If your endpoint only allows a user to query for a single status you would use the singular i.e.

```
/user?status=1
```

Comment: The use of plural vs singular makes it clear to the API user if multiple parameter values can be passed. But is this a defined standard, best practice, or just developer preference? I have found many examples where multiple ids are queried, but the query parameter name is `id`. Is `id` an exception to the rule?

Comment: @James its not a defined standard to my knowledge. I think that the parameter should convey its use, so if I had an array of ids I'd use 'ids', singular id I'd use 'id'. Consistency in naming convention is key in a codebase.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Makes sense. I agree with you on both points (meaning conveyed by using plural & singular names and on being consistent). Thanks also for answering my question about a defined standard.